# Добавить несколько изображение в одну модель

Tags: python, django

Можете помочь я хочу сделать так чтоб в одну модель добавилось несколько img
например добавил изображение и снизу появилось  кнопка добавить ешё

вот мои коды

Модель изображение

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_images/')
is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % self.id
```

Модель статьи который будет добавляться image

```
class Post(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                default=1, 
                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
imgimgin = models.ForeignKey(ProductImage, blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
content = models.TextField()
```

admin.py

```
    class PostModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ["title", "updated", "timestamp"]
        list_display_links = ["updated"]
        list_editable = ["title"]
        list_filter = ["updated", "updated"]
        search_fields = ["title", "content", "categ"]
        fields = (
            'title',
            'content',
            'categ',
            'like',
            'dizlike',
            'image',
            'imgimgin'
            )

        class Meta:
            model = Post


admin.site.register(Post, PostModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(ProductImage)
```

Comment: Тогда `ProductImage` должен ссылаться внешним ключом на `Post`, а `PostModelAdmin`  должен использовать [инлайн](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cоздайте класс а потом подключите как инлайн

```
class ProductImageInline(admin.StackedInline):
  model = ProductImage
  max_num=10
  extra=0

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [ProductImageInline,]
```